# How can I create lag data (all forward combinations) with data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table, lag

I need to create a dataframe with all possible combinations of a variable. I found an example using data.table that works like this:

```
    df <- data.frame("Age"=1:10)
    df <- setDT(df)
    df[,lag.Age1 := c(NA,Age[-.N])]
```

That creates this:

```
        Age lag.Age1
     1:   1       NA
     2:   2        1
     3:   3        2
     ..   ..       ..
     10: 10        9
```

Now, I want to keep adding lagged vectors that produce something like this:

```
        Age lag.Age1  lag.Age2  lag.Age3
     1:   1       NA     NA       NA
     2:   2        1     NA       NA
     3:   3        2     1        NA
     ..   ..       ..    ..       ..
     10: 10        9     8         7
```

I tried this for the third column:

```
df[,lag.Age2 := c(NA,NA,Age[1:8])]
```

But I really don't get how data.table works here. That line runs but it doesn't do anything.

EDIT: what if the dataframe has a group variable and I want the lag to be done by group? For the first lag it is just:

```
df <- data.frame("Age"=1:10, "Group"=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",6)))

df[,lag.Age1 := c(NA,Age[-.N]), by="Group"]
```

How would this be now? note that the groups have different length.

Comment: You could try `shift` : `df[,lag.Age1 := shift(Age,1)];df[,lag.Age2 := shift(Age,2)]`

Answer (score 1):

`data.table::shift()` is very powerful, because you can provide a vector of offsets; For example, if you want `n` lag columns (from 1 to n), you can do this:

```
n=3            
cols = paste0("lag.Age",1:n)
df[, c(cols):=shift(Age,1:n), Group]
```

Output:

```
      Age  Group lag.Age1 lag.Age2 lag.Age3
    <int> <char>    <int>    <int>    <int>
 1:     1      A       NA       NA       NA
 2:     2      A        1       NA       NA
 3:     3      A        2        1       NA
 4:     4      A        3        2        1
 5:     5      B       NA       NA       NA
 6:     6      B        5       NA       NA
 7:     7      B        6        5       NA
 8:     8      B        7        6        5
 9:     9      B        8        7        6
10:    10      B        9        8        7
```

Alternatively:

```
df[, c(paste0("lag.Age",1:3)):=shift(Age,1:3), Group]
```

If you want to have the number of lags vary by group, where the number equals the number of observations in that group-1, then one approach is to do this:

```
# make function to return lags based on length of x
f <- function(x) shift(x,1:(length(x)-1))

# get unique groups
grps= unique(df$Group)

# set as DT, and use lapply()
setDT(df)
grp_lags = lapply(grps, \(g) f(df[Group==g, Age]))
names(grp_lags)<-grps
```

Output:

```
$A
$A[[1]]
[1] NA  1  2  3

$A[[2]]
[1] NA NA  1  2

$A[[3]]
[1] NA NA NA  1


$B
$B[[1]]
[1] NA  5  6  7  8  9

$B[[2]]
[1] NA NA  5  6  7  8

$B[[3]]
[1] NA NA NA  5  6  7

$B[[4]]
[1] NA NA NA NA  5  6

$B[[5]]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA  5
```

Or, if you have okay with lots of extra columns (i.e. for the groups with fewer observations), you can do this:

```
n = df[, .N, Group][,max(N)]
cols = paste0("lag.Age",1:n)
df[, c(cols):=shift(Age,1:n), Group]
```

Output:

```
    Age Group lag.Age1 lag.Age2 lag.Age3 lag.Age4 lag.Age5 lag.Age6
 1:   1     A       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 2:   2     A        1       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 3:   3     A        2        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
 4:   4     A        3        2        1       NA       NA       NA
 5:   5     B       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 6:   6     B        5       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 7:   7     B        6        5       NA       NA       NA       NA
 8:   8     B        7        6        5       NA       NA       NA
 9:   9     B        8        7        6        5       NA       NA
10:  10     B        9        8        7        6        5       NA
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for my initial question. I have one additional question though.
I'll edit the question.

Comment: see edit. shift works just fine with `by`.. `DT[i,j,by]`, so in my last response `i` is empty, `j` is `c(paste0("lag.Age",1:3)):=shift(Age,1:3)` and `by` is  Group

Comment: Thanks. This works for a lag 1:3. But I'm trying to have (m-1) lags for each group, being m the number of observations on each group. So, for Group A this would be 1:3, and for Group 2 this would be 1:5. Do you know how can I do this? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: sure, but do you still want the structure as above? Because it means that you will have as many columns as the largest group (minus 1), so lots of NA columns.. You might consider a different storage structure..

Comment: Yes, I took your code and modified it to get what I finally wanted. I wanted to create all possible forward combinations of Age. After having all the lags in the columns, I used a loop to get everything on the same column and then deleted the NAs. Thank you!